# Python Atributo de clase sin inicializar

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Estoy haciendo una clase en Python para dar de alta productos y necesito un atributo estático que sirva como un contador de los productos que se han registrado. Ese mismo contador es el que voy a usar como idProducto para que se incremente solo. Sin embargo python me exige que inicialice mi atributo estático y si hago eso entonces el contador siempre va a regresar a cero y el idProducto de siempre será el mismo. Por favor qué otra opción tengo?, en java si podía declarar mi atributo estático sin inicializarlo.

```
class Articulos:
    contadorArt=0 #atributo de clase

    def __init__(self, nombreArt, precio):
        self.idArticulo=Articulos.contador()
        self.nombreArt=nombreArt
        self.precio=precio
    
    @classmethod
    def contador(self):
        Articulos.contadorArt=+1
        return Articulos.contadorArt

    def __str__(self):
        return "Articulo numero: "+str(self.idArticulo)+" "+self.nombreArt+"\nPrecio: "+str(self.precio)

    @classmethod
    def cantidadArticulos (self):
        return Articulos.contadorArt

articulo=Articulos("Cereal",45.0)
print(articulo)
articulo2=Articulos("Yogurt",22.0)
print(articulo2)
print(Articulos.cantidadArticulos())
```

Cuando inicializo en cero entonces todos los artículos tienen idArticulo en 1. Mi duda surge porque en Java esto si me funcionaba pero no logro encontrar su equivalente en Python.

Answer (score 5):

El error que tenías era que habías puesto `=+` en lugar de `+=`

La sintaxis `=+1` no es errónea, pero no hace lo que quieres. Lo que hace se entiende mejor si añadimos un espacio: `= +1`. Es decir, simplemente asignas un `+1` que es lo mismo que un 1. Por tanto no era que el atributo se reiniciara a cero, era que en lugar de incrementarlo le asignabas un 1.

Al margen de este error de sintaxis, tienes otro error conceptual y es que confundes `@classmethod` con `@staticmethod`. Creo que todos los `@classmethod` que has puesto en tu código deberían ser `@staticmethod`. La diferencia es la siguiente:

- `@staticmethod` designa un método como estático. Esto es, es un método que puede ser invocado directamente sobre la clase, sin necesidad de instanciar un objeto antes para invocarlo. Por lo tanto no recibe ningún objeto como parámetro (no se pone el `self`)

  Si declaras un método como estático en la clase `A`, puedes invocarlo después de dos formas, a elegir la que más te convenga: directamente sobre la clase: `A.metodo()` o sobre una instancia: `obj = A(); obj.metodo()`. Incluso en el segundo caso se invocaría el método de la clase y no del objeto, y no recibiría `obj` como parámetro.
- `@classmethod` Estos son unos métodos especiales que no necesitarás casi nunca. Como los estáticos, se pueden invocar sobre la clase directamente o sobre una instancia de la misma, pero *sí que reciben un parámetro*. El parámetro que reciben no obstante no es el objeto, sino la propia clase. Por esa razón al parámetro no se le suele llamar `self` (para no confundirse, ya que ese nombre suele referirse a un objeto), sino `cls`.

  Su utilidad está más bien para implementar factorías.

Por tanto, si reescribimos tu código corrigiendo el bug y usando además `@staticmethod` quedaría así:

```
class Articulos:
    contadorArt=0 #atributo de clase

    def __init__(self, nombreArt, precio):
        self.idArticulo=Articulos.contador()
        # En la línea anterior podría haber usado también self.contador()
        self.nombreArt=nombreArt
        self.precio=precio
    
    @staticmethod
    def contador():
        Articulos.contadorArt+=1
        return Articulos.contadorArt

    def __str__(self):
        return "Articulo numero: "+str(self.idArticulo)+" "+self.nombreArt+"\nPrecio: "+str(self.precio)

    @staticmethod
    def cantidadArticulos ():
        return Articulos.contadorArt

articulo=Articulos("Cereal",45.0)
print(articulo)
articulo2=Articulos("Yogurt",22.0)
print(articulo2)

# Las tres llamadas siguientes son en realidad la misma
print(articulo.cantidadArticulos(), articulo2.cantidadArticulos(), Articulos.cantidadArticulos())
```

Resultado:

```
Articulo numero: 1 Cereal
Precio: 45.0
Articulo numero: 2 Yogurt
Precio: 22.0
2 2 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Si bien ya detectaste cuál era tu error sintáctico (`=+`), quiero proveer una solución más *pythonic* que aborde tu caso.

Lo que quieres hacer es, básicamente, tener una variable que contenga la información de cuántas instancias de `Articulo` (`Article`, de ahora en adelante ;) ) se han creado. Esto, en efecto, es un trabajo ideal para una variable de clase.

Ahora bien, ¿cómo podemos actualizar esta variable? Debemos colocar ese código de actualización del contador en un lugar que sepamos que siempre será llamado cuando una instancia nueva de `Article` sea creada.

Las clases en Python incluyen el método `__new__` ([acá](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html) hay un artículo buenísimo que explica a detalle el raciocinio detrás de la concepción de este método, en palabras del mismísimo Guido) que es llamado cada vez que se crea una instancia de ellas. Por lo tanto, este parece ser el sitio ideal para el código de nuestra misión.

La clase `Article`, entonces, se vería de manera similar a lo mostrado a continuación:

```
class Article:

    instances = 0

    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        class_.instances += 1
        return super().__new__(class_)
```

De ahora en adelante, cada vez que se cree un objeto de la clase `Article`, la variable `instances` será actualizada. Cabe destacar que es necesario el uso de `super()` para no alterar el proceso de instanciación que Python provee, a través del llamado del método `__new__` en la clase padre (`object`).

Aplicando esto, y editando el código para hacerlo más *pythonic*, lo que tú tenías quedaría ahora de la siguiente manera:

```
class Article:

    _instances = 0

    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        class_._instances += 1
        return super().__new__(class_)

    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.id = self._instances
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'Articulo número: {self.id} '
            f'{self.name} \n'
            f'Precio: {self.price}'
        )

    @classmethod
    def get_number_of_articles(class_):
        return class_._instances
```

A notar:

- Usamos [interpolación de strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), específicamente F-Strings, en lugar de concatenar las cadenas de caracteres.
- Indicamos con un *leading underscore* que la variable `_instances` no debe ser ni modificada ni accedida fuera de la clase `Article`.
- Usamos un `@classmethod` que sirva como interfaz pública para obtener la variable "privada" (y nótense las comillas) `_instances`, a través de la misma clase `Article`, en lugar de a través de sus instancias.

Se podrá usar la clase así:

```
>>> article = Article('Cereal', 45.0)
>>> print(article)
Articulo número: 1 Cereal 
Precio: 45.0
>>> article_2 = Article('Yogurt', 22.0)
>>> print(article_2)
Articulo número: 2 Yogurt 
Precio: 22.0
>>> Article.get_number_of_articles()
2
```

---

*Nota final*: Si bien esto funciona y mediante mi respuesta intenté transformar tu código para que se apegar más al lenguaje, si estás usando este código en realidad, te sugiero volver a pensar la estructura de tu sistema. Las clase `Article` no debería preocuparse de cuántas instancias se han creado. Me parece que debes separar los *concerns* y hacer una clase aparte (algo tipo `ArticleRepository`) que sea la encargada de gestionar y llevar registro de los artículos creados.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si, más adelante avanzaré a una clase de control exclusiva para la gestión de los Artículos y ahí metería este contador. Lo que sucede es que apenas estoy en mis primeras prácticas en Python y me ha costado mucho trabajo porque aprendí en Java. Y con su respuesta me doy cuenta de que aún me falta mucho por aprender, de verdad creo que Python es toda una Filosofía diferente. Espero en algunos meses más que conozca mejor el lenguaje, poder estar codificando de forma más Pythonica poco a poco.

Comment: Has dado justo en el clavo con lo que has dicho. Python es toda una filosofía. De hecho, si haces en una shell de Python `import this`, verás todo un conjunto de postulados que rigen cómo debe ser el código verdaderamente apegado a este lenguaje. Te recomiendo también el libro *The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python.  Best Practices for Development*, de Kenneth Reitz.

Answer (score 1):

Logré encontrar el error, la lógica de lo que estaba haciendo creo que esta bien, solamente el error estaba en la forma de incrementar el contadorArt dentro del método de clase. Dejo el método corregido.

```
@classmethod 
def contador(self): 
    Articulos.contadorArt=Articulos.contadorArt+1
```